# TOMCAT 9 +Java 8 upgrade issue: The method URLDecode(String) is undefined for the type RequestUtil

Tags: java, java-8, tomcat9

Recently I upgraded my application to Tomcat 9 and Java 8 and deployed my war files. When I launch my application I'm getting errors like,

```
  An error occurred at line: [3] in the jsp file: [/app/myPage.jsp]
  The method URLDecode(String) is undefined for the type RequestUtil
   1: </script>
   2: <%
   3: String fromPage = org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil.URLDecode( "redirect" );
```

in my lib path catalina.jar has the method.
Please guide me on what is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality has been removed in version 9:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/RequestUtil.html

Try UDecoder from Tomcat 9:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/UDecoder.html

or Java 8's built-in decoder:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: Million Thanks KevinB :):) for the timely response..Happy New year:)